# How to intercept click on link in UITextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview, datadetectortypes

Is it possible to perform custom action when user touch autodetected phone link in UITextView. Please do not advice to use UIWebView instead.

And please don't just repeat text from apple classes reference
 - certainly I've already read it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Update: From [ios10](/questions/tagged/ios10),

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange interaction:(UITextItemInteraction)interaction;
```

From [ios7](/questions/tagged/ios7) and Later `UITextView` has the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange *NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(7_0, 10_0, "Use textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:forInteractionType: instead");*
```

to intercept the clicks to links. And this is the best way to do it.

For [ios6](/questions/tagged/ios6) and earlier a nice way to do this is to by subclassing `UIApplication` and overwriting the `-(BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url`

```
@interface MyApplication : UIApplication {

}

@end

@implementation MyApplication


-(BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url{
    if  ([self.delegate openURL:url])
         return YES;
    else
         return [super openURL:url];
}
@end
```

You will need to implement `openURL:` in your delegate.

Now, to have the application start with your new subclass of `UIApplication`, locate the file main.m in your project. In this small file that bootstraps your app, there is usually this line:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

The third parameter is the class name for your application. So, replacing this line for:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"MyApplication", nil);
```

This did the trick for me.

Comment: At last real answer! Simple and cool idea. Thanks, it works. It was long time ago, so I've managed without it already. Still may help in future. Small correction though, result from super in else branch should be returned: return [super openURL:url];

Comment: You could also categorize `UIApplication` and replace the openURL implementation. Though this way it is tricky (but not impossible) to reference the original implementation.

Comment: FYI - I posted a BrowserViewController on GitHub that fully implements this, as well as supporting links clicked from within a UIWebView here: https://github.com/nbuggia/Browser-View-Controller--iPhone-.

Comment: This only seems to work for web links, not autoformatted phone numbers.

Comment: In what method can I set my application's delegate?

Comment: hkcktk: the application delegate is always configured when the app is launched. Your specific subclass is setup in the root xib or storyboard. All of Xcode's templates will create a delegate four you.  Look for a class that implements UIApplicationDelegate.

Comment: `textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange` is deprecated.

Answer (score 54):

In iOS 7 or Later

You can use the following UITextView delegate Method:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
```

The text view calls this method if the user taps or long-presses the URL link. Implementation of this method is optional. By default, the text view opens the application responsible for handling the URL type and passes it the URL. You can use this method to trigger an alternative action, such as displaying the web content at the URL in a web view within the current application.

**Important:**

> Links in text views are interactive only if the text view is
>   selectable but noneditable. That is, if the value of the UITextView
>   the selectable property is YES and the isEditable property is NO.

Comment: I'm glad they added this to the UITextViewDelegate.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll still end up using `UIWebView` if you want to make some other text *the* link and not the URL itself. The `<a>` tag is still the best way to go in that case.

Comment: In case other people see this, you can now make some other text the link.

Answer (score 11):

With Swift 5 and iOS 12, you can use one of the three following patterns in order to interact with links in a `UITextView`.

---

### #1. Using `UITextView`'s [`dataDetectorTypes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618607-datadetectortypes) property.

The simplest way to interact with phone numbers, urls or addresses in a `UITextView` is to use `dataDetectorTypes` property. The sample code below shows how to implement it. With this code, when the user taps on the phone number, a `UIAlertController` pops up.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.text = "Phone number: +33687654321"
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.dataDetectorTypes = [.phoneNumber]
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false

        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(textView)
        textView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}
```

---

### #2. Using `UITextViewDelegate`'s [`textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1649337-textview) method

If you want to perform some custom action instead of making a `UIAlertController` pop up when you tap on a phone number while using `dataDetectorTypes`, you have to make your `UIViewController` conform to `UITextViewDelegate` protocol and implement `textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)`. The code below shows how to implement it:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.delegate = self
        textView.text = "Phone number: +33687654321"
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.dataDetectorTypes = [.phoneNumber]
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false

        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(textView)
        textView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        /* perform your own custom actions here */
        print(URL) // prints: "tel:+33687654321"

        return false // return true if you also want UIAlertController to pop up
    }

}
```

---

### #3. Using [`NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring) and `NSAttributedString.Key.link`

As an alternative, you can use `NSAttributedString` and set a `URL` for its `NSAttributedString.Key.link` attribute.The sample code below shows a possible implementation of it. With this code, when user taps on the attributed string, a `UIAlertController` pops up.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Contact: ")
        let phoneUrl = NSURL(string: "tel:+33687654321")! // "telprompt://+33687654321" also works
        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.link: phoneUrl]
        let phoneAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "phone number", attributes: attributes)
        attributedString.append(phoneAttributedString)

        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.attributedText = attributedString
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false

        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(textView)
        textView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

For Swift 3

```
textView.delegate = self

extension MyTextView: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

        GCITracking.sharedInstance.track(externalLink: URL)
        return true
    }
}
```

or if target is >= IOS 10

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool
```

Answer (score 7):

Swift version:

Your standard UITextView setup should look something like this, don't forget the delegate and dataDetectorTypes.

```
var textView = UITextView(x: 10, y: 10, width: CardWidth - 20, height: placeholderHeight) //This is my custom initializer
textView.text = "dsfadsaf www.google.com"
textView.selectable = true
textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.Link
textView.delegate = self
addSubview(textView)
```

After your class ends add this piece:

```
class myVC: UIViewController {
    //viewdidload and other stuff here
}

extension MainCard: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        //Do your stuff over here
        var webViewController = SVModalWebViewController(URL: URL)
        view.presentViewController(webViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4:

1) Create the following class (subclassed UITextView):

```
import Foundation

protocol QuickDetectLinkTextViewDelegate: class {
    func tappedLink()
}

class QuickDetectLinkTextView: UITextView {

    var linkDetectDelegate: QuickDetectLinkTextViewDelegate?

    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let glyphIndex: Int? = layoutManager.glyphIndex(for: point, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceThroughGlyph: nil)
        let index: Int? = layoutManager.characterIndexForGlyph(at: glyphIndex ?? 0)
        if let characterIndex = index {
            if characterIndex < textStorage.length {
                if textStorage.attribute(NSLinkAttributeName, at: characterIndex, effectiveRange: nil) != nil {
                    linkDetectDelegate?.tappedLink()
                    return self
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

2) Wherever you set up your textview, do this:

```
//init, viewDidLoad, etc
textView.linkDetectDelegate = self

//outlet
@IBOutlet weak var textView: QuickDetectLinkTextView!

//change ClassName to your class
extension ClassName: QuickDetectLinkTextViewDelegate {
    func tappedLink() {
        print("Tapped link, do something")
    }
}
```

If you're using storyboard, make sure your textview looks like this in the right pane identity inspector:
[image]

Voila!  Now you get the link tap immediately instead of when the URL shouldInteractWith URL method

Comment: also:  if you want the url to not be handled, just set the shouldInteractWith method to return false

Comment: Think this has a bunch of issues, such as what happens when you don't tap a link. Ie I don't think the text view will work normally anymore, since nil is being returned. The selection will also change when you tap a link,  because in that case, self is returned.

Comment: works great for me, you need to handle such cases for your needs

Comment: **weak** var linkDetectDelegate: QuickDetectLinkTextViewDelegate?

Comment: @vyachaslav not for me, you must be doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

`application:handleOpenURL:` is called when another app opens *your* app by opening a URL with a scheme your app supports.  It's not called when your app begins opening a URL.

I think the only way to do what Vladimir wants is to use a UIWebView instead of a UITextView.  Make your view controller implement UIWebViewDelegate, set the UIWebView's delegate to the view controller, and in the view controller implement `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` to open `[request URL]` in a view instead of quitting your app and opening it in Mobile Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried that myself but you can try to implement `application:handleOpenURL:` method in your application delegate - it looks like all `openURL` request pass through this callback.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you would intercept the detected data link, or what type of function you need to run.  But you may be able to utilize the didBeginEditing TextField method to run a test/scan through the textfield if you know what your looking for..such as comparing text strings that meet ###-###-#### format, or begin with "www." to grab those fields, but you would need to write a little code to sniff through the textfields string, reconize what you need, and then extract it for your function's use.   I don't think this would be that difficult, once you narrowed down exactly what it is that you wanted and then focussed your if() statement filters down to very specific matching pattern of what you needed.

Of couse this implies that the user is going to touch the textbox in order to activate the didBeginEditing().  If that is not the type of user interaction you were looking for you could just use a trigger Timer, that starts on ViewDidAppear() or other based on need and runs through the textfields string, then at the end of you run through the textfield string methods that you built, you just turn the Timer back off.