# How can I over-ride the UITextView link detection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uitextview

I have a UITextView that is auto-detecting link URL's. Instead of opening it in Safari, I want to present my own modal view controller that contains a webview so my users stay in-app.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps this will be helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543967/how-to-intercept-click-on-link-in-uitextview/4338011#4338011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can.

Where a UIWebView will tell its delegate when a link is tapped, a UITextView doesn't provide that kind of info.

You could use a UIWebView instead of a UITextView, but that's a workaround...

Answer (score 0):

By all accounts this is possible with the following:

```
- (void)webView:(id)fp8 decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(id)fp12 request:(id)fp16 frame:(id)fp20 decisionListener:(id)fp24;
```

Credit goes to Muthu.chidambar here http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=745879 (if it works that is ;-) )