# A class like UITextView, but with the ability to handle URL clicks

Tags: ios, url, uiscrollview, uitextview

I am wondering if there is something already like this out there.  But I basically want something like UITextView to display text with embedded links.  However, I want to be able to handle the URL clicks as a delegate.

I've read a few posts like the following:

[How to intercept click on link in UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543967/how-to-intercept-click-on-link-in-uitextview)

However, I really don't want to override the openURL method.  My app works with lots of webServer data, and I don't want to keep creating exceptions for different hosts in the openURL method.

I guess my questions is, is there another way to intercept the click on UITextView?

My alternative is to write my own, with a UIScrollView, and use a TTTAttributedLabel (https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) inside it.  But am looking for suggestions, or alternatives.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use UIWebView + Local HTML instead of UITextView.

And use the -(BOOL )webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType )navigationType delegate to handle the URL clicks,like:

```
-(BOOL )webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType )navigationType
{

  NSURL * clickedURL=[request URL];

  //Do something here.

  return NO;

}
```

Comment: Sounds interesting.  Can you comment more about the local html, I am just trying to show text.    How do I get an NSString into the UIWebview?  Do I convert the NSString to a NSData, and then use the "- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL" method?  But I don't have a baseURL.

Comment: You can simply generate a HTML string by adding <a> marks. For example: NSString * originalText=@"Hello"; NSString * HTMLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<A>%@</A>",originalText]; Then use the loadHTMLString method, pass HTMLString to string and pass nil to baseURL ;-)