# How to get click event of email link in UITextView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview

I am new in iPhone development. I am doing a contact us page. Here I uses a UITextView to display the details. In it, there is a email address link (abc@company.com). When a user tapped on the email link, the iPhone's default mail app needs to be appear. But I don't know how to get the click event of the email link in UITextView.

How can I achieve this ?.

I know how to load mail app. But before that I want to do some other things. So how can i get a click event when user taps on the email link in UITextView ?

Comment: This question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543967/how-to-intercept-click-on-link-in-uitextview

Comment: how did you get this done?

Answer (score 0):

The iOS SDK does not expose this event in a `UITextView`. If you want to intercept a tap on an email link, you will have to use a `UIWebView` instead of the text view.

Comment: Yeah. I tried it with UIWebview. (<a href="">abc@company.com</a>). how can i get the click event while clicking the email ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with `uiwebview` in your html content try this  <`a href="mailto:abc@company.com">`