# UILabel - string as text and links

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` whose text I am getting from a server. Some of the text is to be identified as links, and on touching those links some action should be performed. e.g.

NSString *str = @"My phone number is [645-345-2345](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and my address is [xyz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)";

This is the complete text for `UILabel`. I have only one `UILabel` for displaying this text (Text is dynamic. I just gave an example.). On clicking these links I need to perform actions like navigating to some different screen or make a call.
I know that I can display such text with help of **OHAttributedLabel**. And the links can be displayed as follows :

```
[label1 addCustomLink:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.foodreporter.net"] inRange:[txt rangeOfString:someString]];
```

But I wonder how can I make these **text links** perform some action like navigation to different screen or making a call.
Let me know if more explanation is required.

Comment: From 2013 onwards ... you just use UITextView and click "detect links" in interfaceBuilder ... it's that simple.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116820/how-to-make-customlink-touchable-in-ohattributedlabel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create tap-able "links" in the NSAttributedText of a UILabel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/create-tap-able-links-in-the-nsattributedtext-of-a-uilabel)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You can add custom actions to any of the available `UILabel` replacements that support links using a *fake* **URL scheme** that you'll intercept later:

```
TTTAttributedLabel *tttLabel = <# create the label here #>;
NSString *labelText = @"Lost? Learn more.";
tttLabel.text = labelText;
NSRange r = [labelText rangeOfString:@"Learn more"]; 
[tttLabel addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"action://show-help"] withRange:r];
```

Then, in your `TTTAttributedLabelDelegate`:

```
- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    if ([[url scheme] hasPrefix:@"action"]) {
        if ([[url host] hasPrefix:@"show-help"]) {
            /* load help screen */
        } else if ([[url host] hasPrefix:@"show-settings"]) {
            /* load settings screen */
        }
    } else {
        /* deal with http links here */
    }
}
```

[TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) is a fork of OHAttributedLabel.

If you want a more complex approach, have a look to [Nimbus Attributed Label](http://jverkoey.github.com/nimbus/group___nimbus_attributed_label.html). It support custom links out-of-the-box.

Comment: Just to add to this: the custom url will need to have a `//` such as `action://show-help`. Otherwise, the scheme will be the only valid url property. (everything else will be nil without the double slash).

Comment: Thanks alot , I have make the label attributed and inserted the link into special range. But I am unable to change it's font size. Help please.

Comment: any new approach for ios 6+ ? since UILabel supports attributedStrings

Comment: tttattributedLabel source is not available in github is there any alternate for this.

Comment: @Raghav You can find TTTAtributedLabel here https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel Found after hours of search, Ufffff!!!!!

Comment: how to add a link in label when label.text is a NSMutableAttributedString with appending two and more attributedString, at a specific attributedString ?@djromero

Comment: what if label.text is dynamic(coming from API), don`t know the string size then how to add  link on that specific string .

Comment: @MetaSnarf are you really asking about a 4 years old question? Please, add a new question and maybe reference this one.

Answer (score 17):

You can use UITextView with Phone numbers and links detection YES, scrolling disabled YES user interaction enabled YES, instead of UILabel.

Comment: From 2013 onwards .. it's this simple

Comment: @Ganesh, why scrolling disabled?

Answer (score 8):

My project has successfully used OHAttributedLabel for this. Check out the

`-(BOOL)attributedLabel:(OHAttributedLabel*)attributedLabel shouldFollowLink:(NSTextCheckingResult*)linkInfo;`

method in `OHAttributedLabelDelegate` ([link](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/blob/master/OHAttributedLabel.h)). It allows you to decide what happens when a link is clicked. If you look at the source for [the example from the OHAttributedLabel project](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/blob/master/AttributedLabel%20Example/Classes/AttributedLabel_ExampleAppDelegate.m), it's used to display an alert. If you returned `NO` in this case (to keep the default action from happening too), you could just do whatever you wanted like navigation, etc.

Note however that this requires that you can determine the action correctly just from the text. For our project, we used a slightly fancier solution, where the server sent us text with tags in them and a list of commands to perform for each tag.

Answer (score 6):

There a project called [FancyLabel](http://furbo.org/stuff/FancyLabel_1.0.zip) that is about what you need. It might need some customization though.
Also, I think [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) has this functionality, but it might be an overkill if you don't already use it.

There's also a much simpler solution, if all of your links are phones \ addresses \ urls. You can simply use a UITextView instead of a UILabel. It has auto detection of phones, address, etc. (just check the boxes in IB)

You can also have custom actions in response to click events on those links by overriding openURL, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543967/how-to-intercept-click-on-link-in-uitextview)

Is there a specific reason that you must use a UILabel instead of a UITextView? 
Note that a lot of the implementations of attributed labels inherit from UIView or don't implement all of UILabel's functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You can use custom button to give a look like of link ..Also you can add gesture on the custom label if you dont want to use button ..

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userTappedOnLink:)];
// if labelView is not set userInteractionEnabled, you must do so
[labelView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[labelView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

Comment: I have to use single label only. I can't place a button there.

Comment: Can you please explain your second option. It might be useful here.

Comment: The thing is that links are at different positions on the label. The positions are dynamic. How can this approach work for me?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a fan of being forced to use `UITextView` or a third party lib when all I need is a lightweight label that renders links (and that tells me when they're tapped!)

Here's my attempt at a lightweight `UILabel` subclass able to detect link taps.  The approach is different from others I've seen in that it gains access to the `UILabel`'s shared `NSLayoutManager` via a delegate callback added to `NSTextStorage` via a category extension.  The beauty is that `UILabel` performs its native layout and drawing - other `UILabel` replacements often augment or replace the native behavior with an additional `NSLayoutManager`/`NSTextContainer`.

Probably App Store safe, but somewhat fragile - use at your own risk!

https://github.com/TomSwift/TSLabel

Comment: It doesn't have automatic detection.