# How to make CustomLink touchable in OHAttributedLabel

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am successfully adding links to a `UILabel` via `OHAttributeLabel` and `-(void)addCustomLink:(NSURL*)linkUrl inRange:(NSRange)range;`  In other words, the correct range is underlined and looks like a link.

However, I cannot click/touch on the link. Is there anything else that must be done that the `addCustomLink` method on the range of text?  FWIW, I am not using Interface Builder even though much of the `OHAttributedLabel` code makes references to `IBOutlet`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The required code in this case was simply:

```
[myLabel setDelegate:self];
```

And in context for those interested is:

```
descriptionLabel.attributedText = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:@"foo"];
[myLabel addCustomLink:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] inRange:NSMakeRange(myLocation, myLength)];
[myLabel setDelegate:self];
```

Many thanks!