# Detecting taps on link in NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I'm dynamically building views and printing attributed text on them using drawInRect:. Some of the text may include web links. How can I detect taps on web links so I can load the link in a UIWebView? I'm not using a UILabel, UITextView or UITextField to display the text because the text includes a mixture of text and images.

This is some of the code in drawRect for my UIView subclass that draws the text.

```
//draw the text

    NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.message.text];

    [attString beginEditing];

    NSArray *arrString = [attString.string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    for (NSString *str in arrString)
    {
        if ([str rangeOfString:@"http://" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound ||
            [str rangeOfString:@".com"    options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound ||
            [str rangeOfString:@".gov"    options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound ||
            [str rangeOfString:@".org"    options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound ||
            [str rangeOfString:@".edu"    options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound ||
            [str rangeOfString:@".net"    options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound ||
            [str rangeOfString:@".xxx"    options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            NSRange rng = [attString.string rangeOfString:str];

            NSString *url;

            if ([str rangeOfString:@"http://"  options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound &&
                [str rangeOfString:@"https://" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound)
            {
                url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", str];
            }
            else
            {
                url = str;
            }

            [attString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:[NSURL URLWithString:url] range:rng];
        }
    }

    [attString endEditing];

    CGSize theSize;
    theSize = [attString.string sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CHAT_TEXT_WIDTH, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, theSize.width, theSize.height);
    textRect.origin.x += 10;
    textRect.origin.y += 10;

    if (self.type == MESSAGE_BOX_RECEIVE) {
        textRect.origin.x += ARROW_WIDTH;
    }

    [attString drawInRect:textRect];
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: This might give you some ideas. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888941/nsattributedstring-tappable-ios

Comment: Can you post your code?  I can suggest some ideas, but it really depends on how your custom views work.

Comment: @WolfLink I edited my post to include the code for how I draw the text. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is draw the text with TextKit (introduced in iOS 7). This allows you to interpret taps by way of TextKit as well.

Here's a downloadable example project where I display a list of words and detect which word the user tapped on (and I even respond by momentarily highlighting the word):

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p543drawingWithTextKit/ch23p815attributedStringDrawing3/StyledText.swift

Comment: @DougSmith Do you want the original where it moved to, or do you want the updated iOS 8 / Swift version of that example?

Comment: The iOS 8/Swift version would be great.

Comment: @DougSmith You got it!

Comment: @matt, Is there a Objective-C version too. ? We're still living in Objective-C world.