# Clickable UILabel with NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

Is it possible to have a linkable text with `NSAttributedString` (I don't want to use `UIWebView` and html)?

I need a `UILabel` that shows the following text:

"To download the app **tap here**"

And **tap here** should be clickable so I can perform some action when user tap it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting taps on link in NSAttributedString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617948/detecting-taps-on-link-in-nsattributedstring)

Comment: [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) is what you want!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by [ResponsiveLabel](https://github.com/hsusmita/ResponsiveLabel/). Here is the sample usage.

```
PatternTapResponder action = ^(NSString *tappedString){
  //Action to be performed
};
// label is of type ResponsiveLabel
[label enableStringDetection:@"Tap Here" withAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor],
                                                             RLTapResponderAttributeName:action}];
```