# Can I change a specific string into uibutton in a uitableview?

Tags: objective-c, string, uitableview, uibutton

Can I change a specific string in the cell of uitableview into a UIBUTTON ?
for example, "There is a fox on the road" << I want to change the word fox into uibutton which contains the label fox.

This is because I want to detect specific string in a large text and want to insert a hyperlink-like action programmatically in that button.(or just underlining the specific text is O.K.)

problem is
1. detecting the accurate point of the word to set the frame of uibutton. Even difficult when the text is flowing when the orientation changed. 
2. so we should manage the button which added to subview like a text string. But I'm not sure if it is possible.

(If the text is inside the UIwebview,  it seems easy( embracing the string with underlining tag) but I cannot insert uiwebviews inside every row of the tableviewcell!)

Comment: You could also add a `UITextView` to the cell instead. You could set the `dataDetectorTypes` to handle link detection.

Comment: Subclass UILabel and do some touch handling.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839464/uilabel-string-as-text-and-links