# Hyperlink functionality for label in ios native app

Tags: ios, hyperlink, uilabel, uisearchbar, xcode5

I have image which contains tags(showed with # symbols) when i click on a particular tag then i need to call a web service by passing the same tag on which i clicked and i need to push another view.

After clicked on the tag i need to perform **search** functionality which tag i have sent.It may have multiple tags for single image like that i have more than on image.

Great appreciation for answer.thank you.

Attached the screen shot below placed the tags with # symbol before.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of open source libraries that help with what you want to do. [Check out this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839464/uilabel-string-as-text-and-links) to another StackOverflow post that suggests using TTAttributedLabel.

Comment: its really great answer to me, Thanq very much for the support. Its worked fine.Thanq again.

Comment: How can i set text colour for TTAttributedLabel by default black colour is appeared. I want to change it with YELLOW colour.