# open a link into a clickable label (RTLabel)

Tags: ios, label, action

Using a [RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel), I show eficently  this html string:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Example Street, 1,  Rome">Example Street, 1</a>
```

as:  Example Street, 1.  Its clickable, but no action is done. Any RTLabel user Knows how active an action? 
Or if there is some altrnative to open in safari that link (in this case to show a map).

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839464/uilabel-string-as-text-and-links use this

Comment: Thanks for answer. Bu is not so clear how could use my link into TTTAttributedLabel

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Set the RTLabel delegate as:

```
[rtlabel setDelegate:self];
```

On tapping the link, the below function gets called. Handle accordingly:

```
-(void)rtLabel:(id)rtLabel didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL*)url
{

RTLabel * label = (RTLabel*)rtLabel;

[self openBrowserViewForURL:[url absoluteString] pageTitle:label.text];

}
```