# show initial text as an link in SLComposeViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, social-networking, sharing

I want to `setinitialtext` in such a way when it's posted to timeline. it should say like below and i want to set a url behind the seen for `GlanseApp` text only

```
NSString *KSocialSharingTextFBPT=@" Just discovered this great item via [GlanseApp](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/glanse/id762075664?mt=8) for iPhone"
```

how can i achive this ?

Here is the code for sharing

```
SLComposeViewController *composeController = [SLComposeViewController 
           composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
[composeController setInitialText:KSocialSharingTextFBPT];
[composeController addImage:image];
[composeController addURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[product objectForKey:@"producturl"]]];
composeController.completionHandler =^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    switch(result) {
            //  This means the user cancelled without sending the Tweet
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            break;
            //  This means the user hit 'Send'
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            break;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not support rich text (RTF) like MacOS does. The only UI object that supports clickable text links directly is UIWebView.
You can try [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839464/uilabel-string-as-text-and-links) link if it helps you.