# Convert text to hyperlink, assign to UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In the below code I am detecting the *url* from string. now I need to put hyperlink only to detected "url" and assign to `UILabel`  whenever I click on this *url* it should go to browser, how to do this?

Code:

```
NSString *string = descPost.text;
NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [linkDetector matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches)
{
    if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink)
    {
        NSURL *url = [match URL];
        NSLog(@"found URL: %@", url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8839464/792677

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you should do is you should create a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on a `UILabel` and when that `UILabel` is tapped on, you should open the url.

Create the gesture like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = 
 [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                         action:@selector(myAction:)];
[myLabel addGestureRecognizer:gr];
gr.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
```

Next write this `delegate` method when tap is pressed:

```
- (void) myAction: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) gr {
    // write code to open the url here
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

Comment: what should i do when NSString consist a normal string and URL

Comment: You need to separate the url first from the string before calling openURL.
P.S for converting url to string, use
`string = [url absoluteString];`
for converting string to url, use 
`url = [[NSURL alloc] URLWithString:string]`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is, put you link on button instead of label because label has not it own click event/action so you need to use tap gesture for apply clickable feature on label where button has it's own [`forControlEvents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uicontrol_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlEvents) so you can easily handle it. remain thing for an underline of link then put background image of button that look like an underline.

For convert `URL` to `NSString`

```
NSString *urlString = [myURL absoluteString];
```

Otherwise all the information you can get from **@Khawar Ali's** answer :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is, use a UIButton set clear color in background view, and make a IBAction method to manage the action of open URL.

in .h

```
-(IBAction)openUrl:(id)sender;
```

in .m

```
-(IBAction)openUrl:(id)sender{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

}
```

Like our friend said.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
 UILabel *yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 100, 200, 40)]; // according your requirement
 yourLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 UITapGestureRecognizer *linked = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(LinkedToURL:)];
 [yourLabel addGestureRecognizer:linked];
 linked.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
 linked.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
 [self.view addSubview:yourLabel];

 - (void) LinkedToURL: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) linked
 {
    // write your code here for linked with your urls
 }
```