# UILabel with Multiple links

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

Hello I am trying to tappable UILabel similar to Facebook's like text, Label's text would be similar to

```
"You, Steve and 50 others like this."
```

Where "You", "Steve" and "50 others" should be tappable separately.

I am trying my luck with NSAttributedString but it is not helping me, Can anyone help me to find a way ?

Comment: This might be help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839464/uilabel-string-as-text-and-links

Comment: Thanks @Mrunal I think that it will lead me to solution

Comment: @Kampai I think its for UITextView

Comment: Glad to know that. You might require three separate UILables for that. But give a try first.

Comment: @Mrunal no need of three separate UILables

Comment: Try this, use method in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20633388/3604161 to calculate relative location of words you want to make tappable, add tap gesture recognizer to label, after tap compare locations

Answer (score 1):

try this, but it's not for label but it's for textView.

```
    NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"firstsecond"];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(5,6)];




//[string addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];

[string addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.in"] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];



[string addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com"] range:NSMakeRange(5,6)];



self.txtView.attributedText=string;
self.txtView.scrollEnabled = NO;
self.txtView.editable = NO;
self.txtView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
self.txtView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
self.txtView.delegate = self;
 }
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)url inRange:        (NSRange)characterRange
 {
    return YES;
  }
```

Comment: don't forget to <UITextViewDelegate>

Comment: "Links in text views are interactive only if the text view is selectable but noneditable." - May be use to someone, I waste lot of time for this.