# Clickable username and hashtag in UILabel (Not UIWebView!)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilabel, clickable

The idea is for example there is a UILabel (like in Instagram)
"User1 started following User2"
I want that when we click either on chunk of text 'User1' or 'User2' it does some action(Not opening like usual link in UIWebView)

Tried TTTAttributedLabel , didn't find anything which will fit me exactly.

Comment: try [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a method will force you to make two of them (User 1 and User 2) and align it every time you draw it. I think it's better to make a category ( or Swift extension) of UILabel that gets it's frame and add a gesture recognizer with that frame bounds

Comment: I thought of that :) But seems like I finally managed to find a proper solution  using TTTAttributedLabel here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8926077/4229173 .
The idea is to attach a fake hyperlink to to button ,but when link is clicked it will do some action instead of opening UIWebView.

Answer (score 3):

in case you haven't found something yet, you could also try **[ActiveLabel.swift](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift)** which is an `UILabel` drop-in replacement **supporting Hashtags (#), Mentions (@) and URLs (http://)** written in Swift.

[image]

Here is a simple example:

```
import ActiveLabel

let label = ActiveLabel()

label.text = "This is a post with #hashtags and a @userhandle."
label.hashtagColor = .blueColor()
label.handleHashtagTap { print("Success. You just tapped the \($0) hashtag") }
```

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of the library.*

Comment: Thanks schickling for share. Works for swift 1.2?

Comment: No, unfortunately Swift 2 only at the moment.

Comment: Hello @schickling , AvtiveLabel does not support image content of NSTextAttachment

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new button. It can do everything a label can do, and also have actions. You can easily update the text of a button by using:

```
exampleButton.setTitle("example", forState: .Normal)
```

And you can add an action like this:

```
    @IBAction func myExample(sender: UIButton) {

    //do action

    }
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: thank you , but it's not what i wanted ,button will not align like a part of a text.

Comment: What do you mean? A button has every capability that a label has.