# Displaying Hyperlink in UIlabel

Tags: ios, uitableview, hyperlink, uilabel

I have to display data from server which is coming with hyperlink.
Ex: `NSString *messageString = @"Click <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">here</a>&nbsp;";`

I know that in web view its easy to display but we need to display in UitableView.

I have tried [KIlabel](https://github.com/Krelborn/KILabel), [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) but this was of no help as they are detecting only link not hyperlink.

So how will I display this kind of data in UitableView.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541676/ios-uitextview-or-uilabel-with-clickable-links-to-actions

Comment: This one is pre generated text with some tag. This is totally different from what I am looking for

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839464/uilabel-string-as-text-and-links

Comment: Are you doing any action on selecting the UITableView cells? If no you can display the link in a webView after selecting the UITableViewCell of the UITableView.

Comment: Have you got the solution? I have same issue and I tried all KILabel,TTTAttributedLabel,ZSWTappableLabel.