# Adding dynamic tags with title to UITableView header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, header, tags

I want to add dynamic tags with title into table view header when user select row(s).
Like if user selects 5 different cities from table view then I want to add those selected cities as different tags into table view header so that user can see selections with horizontal scrolling or anything else whichever suits best.
How can I achieve such functionality?

Any help would be much appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: you can use collection view following library to display tags.  [link](https://github.com/gtsif21/UITags) Add Collection view as header of tableview

Comment: were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding Collection View into the header of Table View.

1. Create an Array which will store selected row value.
2. Reload or Update the collection view with selected array data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, your option can be done, but I want to show those selections as tag like as we show all the hashtags. So is there any open source library or code section to do that ?

Comment: check this : [STTweetLabel](https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/STTweetLabel) and [ActiveLabel](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift) and see if you can modify these according to your requirement. Also this :[TTTAttributedLabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839464/uilabel-string-as-text-and-links/8926077#8926077)

Answer (score 0):

Have a `UIScrollView` just above the `UITableView` in `StoryBoard`.
When you get into `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method call following method,

```
- (void)addLabel:(NSString *)cityName {

[array addObject:cityName];

UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.frame = CGRectMake(array.count*44, 0, 44, 44);
label.text = cityName;
[sview addSubview:label];
[sview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(array.count*44, 44)];
```

}

1. Here array is , object which holds the list of cities selected
2. `UIScrollView` is , a scroll view which is added above the `UITableView` in storyboard.
3. Every time when you call `addLabel` method by passing selected cityName, initialise a new `UILabel` with required properties and add that to `UIScrollView`. Here the 'x' origin of the `UILabel` is changing based on the number of elements added to array.
4. At the end set the `contentSize` to `UIScrollView` , so that scroll view scrolls till there.

If you need more customisation to showcase labels in scrollview, you can have a `UIView` with whatever the customisation you want, and then add the `UILabel` to `UIView`. At the end add this `UIView` to `UIScrollView`.