# Table View Cell Label text (Column text) use as a link

Tags: ios, objective-c, hyperlink, label, uilabel

I have a table view which is populated by data. Every table view cell has five columns. Every column populate data via UILabel class. That means in each cell datas are populated via five UILabel.

Now I want to make a column text / UILabel class text (label.text) linkable.
What is the procedure?
How can I make a UILabel text link able?

For clarification I am giving web link.

http://www.manningrandc.com/projects/projects.php

My table view will be like as the first table of the link and one or more column text/ label text will be linkable.

Comment: Now I want to make a column text / UILabel class text (label.text) linkable? to whom you want to link those?

Comment: you want to make text as clickable link ?. like url ?

Comment: please explain in brief.. i didnt get your Question...

Comment: Try this [link](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel/).

Comment: See the link provided in the question. 
A table view has populated some data and one or two of its rows are linkable. I just want to know how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Inst ed of Label you can use Button and on click of button add function which will help you to work as link clickable.

Comment: Thanks bro, but I need Label.

Comment: what i did in that cases i use lable to show text and use button which is placed exactly over that lable with clear background colour

Answer (score 0):

Visit [UILabel - string as text and links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839464/uilabel-string-as-text-and-links)

OR

Use UIButton and add a delegate to it and use as you required