# Detect Click on nsurl on uitextview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, overriding, uitextview

I have a URL in my textview and when we click on this url it opens this url in default safari. and I want to detect this event. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543967/how-to-intercept-click-on-link-in-uitextview)

but its not working for me. can any one suggest me how i do this. Provide me a sample for this.

My application deligate is UIResponder type.

Comment: This a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543967/how-to-intercept-click-on-link-in-uitextview

Comment: @NicolasManzini If you carefully read my post, What i Wrote. This not worked for me.???

Comment: sorry you're right. By the way i think the best you can do is use a uiwebview as I did. You'll get easier way to interecept click and you can cusomize link colors

Answer (score 2):

the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543967/how-to-intercept-click-on-link-in-uitextview) works as expected.

create `New File`, select `Objective-C Class`

- Class: `MyApplication`
- Subclass of: `UIApplication`

paste this code in the `.m` file:

```
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url {
    if  ([self handleOpenURL:url])
        return YES;
    else
        return [super openURL:url];
}
- (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL*)url {
    NSLog(@"my url handler");
    return YES;
}
```

next open your `main.m` and change the third parameter

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([SampleAppDelegate class]));
```

to your `UIApplication`-subclass name

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"MyApplication", NSStringFromClass([SampleAppDelegate class]));
```

Comment: I already try this. But when I changed the main.m file then it displaying error and application not compiled.

Comment: I have it tried myself before posting and ensured it is working. How did you named your custom `UIApplication` subclass? … what is the error saying?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this GitHub project: [MSTextView](https://github.com/marksands/MSTextView)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But actually MSTextView is not a TextView. Its type of UIVIEW. I have already added textview in my application so now i do not want to replace all text view with MSTEXTVIEW.

Comment: Ok, so what's your problem with the first solution you've posted?

Comment: I added this in my main.m file but its not working..
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"MyApplication", nil);

openlink method is not called.
    [pool release];
    return retVal;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just need to display a static label with links, we have a fairly powerful attributed label in Nimbus that you may wish to check out:

http://docs.nimbuskit.info/group___nimbus_attributed_label.html

The label uses CoreText and NSAttributedString, so it is built on core Apple technologies. It acts in every way like a UILabel. Here's an example of implementing the NIAttributedLabel delegate:

https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus/blob/master/examples/attributedlabel/BasicAttributedLabel/BasicAttributedLabel/src/MashupViewController.m#L92

More info:
http://nimbuskit.info/

Comment: Sorry. I do not need label. I need uitextview. Bcoz i already completed application so now its not possible to change on all places.