# Open html links in the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, url

Is it possible to handle the call of an URL Scheme inside the same app?

Here's an example:
There is an html link in my app that opening would trigger safari. What I want to do is to tap on that link and that no matter where i am in the app a viewcontroller gets pushed with a webview on it.

If this is possible, where I have to do it? If I handle URL Scheme's calls i need to do it on the app's delegate. Where should i do it in this case? If the viewcontroller needs to be pushed, who is the responsible of pushing it? The appdelegate or the view controller thats currently on screen?

Thanks :)

Comment: You can use Tap gesture recogniser for this.

Comment: Please check my [Question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945439/detect-click-on-nsurl-on-uitextview

Hope it will helps you.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945439/detect-click-on-nsurl-on-uitextview)

I faced the same problem. Hope it will helps you.

Thanks

Comment: this is sort of what im looking for. But once I subclass the app delegate, who is the one resposible of pushing the new view controller?

Comment: Other things will be same as normal application.

Answer (score 2):

1. `UITapGestureRecognizer`, if your link is in a label:

   ```
   UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openLink:)];
   [yourLinkLabel addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
   gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
   gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
   ```
2. If it is a link inside a web page loaded in `UIWebView`, then you can use:`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType`. It will be called every time the user taps a link in the `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 0):

Well its kind of annoying to involve view controller. I found it easier to use javascript to load new links/content within the page. That way one webview is involved and the data/html files get shuffled. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Use this code in the current controller

```
WebViewController *objWebViewController     =   [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
                objWebViewController.m_strHtml=[NSString stringWithString:@"www.google.com"];//m_strHtml is a NSString variable in WebViewController class
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:objWebViewController animated:YES];
                [objContentWebViewController release];
```

Use this in the WebViewController

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:m_strHtml];
        NSURLRequest * req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        [url release];
        [Webview loadRequest:req];
        [req release];
```

ELse you can load the the html inside a web view  and the web view opens the links inside it
as default . Use the following code.

```
m_strHtml=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"<html><body>%@</body></html>",m_strHtmlContent];//m_strHtmlContent is string variable to store the html content

        [Webview loadHTMLString:m_strHtml baseURL:Nil]; 
        Webview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```