# TTTAttributedLabel and popover for link

Tags: ios, ipad, label, uipopovercontroller

Is it possible to detect `CGRect` of link text or `CGPoint` of position, to show popover (on ipad) for clicked link in `TTTAttributedLabel`?
I need to show popover on clicked link with `TTTAttributedLabel`.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this with the TTTAttributedLabel. If you just need to know where the link is, you could register where the user touches. However, that won't give you any specific point of the link like the center or beginning.

Comment: Yeap, i transmit CGPoint of touch to my controller, and after i show popover. But i hope to search link mid point. Another question what to do with line separated links.. Anyway, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do this by modifying the TTTAttributedLabel to support this behavior.

1) Modify the delegate method:

```
- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label
   didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url
                atPoint:(CGPoint)point;
```

2) In the `TTTAttributedLabel.m` source, modify the `touchesEnded:withEvent:` and grab the touch point and pass this onto the delegate method.

```
    switch (result.resultType) {
        case NSTextCheckingTypeLink:
            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(attributedLabel:didSelectLinkWithURL:atPoint:)]) {
                UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
                CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
                [self.delegate attributedLabel:self didSelectLinkWithURL:result.URL atPoint:touchPoint];
                return;
```

3) In the view controller, you will need to convert that touch point to be in relative coordinates to the view controller's view:

```
#pragma mark TTTAttributedLabelDelegate
- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label
   didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url 
                atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
        CGPoint normalizedPoint = [self convertPoint:point fromView:label];        

        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] ...
        [actionSheet showFromRect:CGRectMake(normalizedPoint.x, normalizedPoint.y-kSensibleOffset, 10, 10)
                           inView:label
                         animated:YES];
    }
#pragma mark -
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't want to do this at the gesture level by trying to keep track of position. Since you have a link, just override `openURL` and do whatever you want when you intercept the link click. More details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543967/how-to-intercept-click-on-link-in-uitextview).

Comment: I need to show popover(with arrow) on link click. Are u understand question?

Comment: Yes, I understand. What I'm saying is don't try to track touches, just let the link notify you and then you can launch the popover.

Comment: Where from i must launch popover? Any CGRect with comes with 'notification'? Cant understand what you mean, sorry.