# HTML "on click" event on ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am importing all tags of a HTML page to `UITextView`. but i have few `on click` events like mail and phone in this `HTML` tags. how can i detect that `on click` event and open it in `UIWebView`.

Comment: Have a look in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543967/how-to-intercept-click-on-link-in-uitextview

Comment: no not same question, i want to call a action which is in HTML into iphone programming

Comment: do you edit your textview? if no then use textview delegate methods. Also have a look on this http://benscheirman.com/2009/07/detecting-a-tap-on-a-uitextview

Comment: you mean you want to display string in to UIWebView in some porsion like hyperlink and you want to get clickivent of it right...? then i provide some code if you want like this..?

Comment: @fibnochi: i am fine with UITextview and links in UITextview. i want to import "on Click" event from HTML to ios.

Comment: @NitinGohel: were is the code nitin? thanks in advance

Comment: wait i just put my answer

Comment: you have to right your own javascript functions to detect tap event. I have done similar thing but I used UIWebView.

Comment: display your string into `WebView` its better and easy to use as par my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose are you displaying String in `UIWebView` like bellow But First you must configure your webView outlet and connect proper `Delegate` then put below code in to `ViewWillApear`:-

> [webview loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 
> Have an enquiry for %@? Click hear and we will be in touch with you.* {margin:0;padding:0; font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;text-align:justify}", yourStringDiscription,YourHyperlinkWord] baseURL:nil];

in Above script this line:-
`:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body  text=\"#000000\">%@ <br>Have an enquiry for %@? Click <a href=\"inapp://\">hear</a>`

in first %@ is for String of contain and second %@ for your Hyparlink

**Now**

you can get click event of this `webViewdelegate` method

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {

       //Got even here put breck point
       return NO;
    }

    return YES;

}
```

you can got click event in above delegate hope you undastood what i am saying and hope its help's you

Answer (score 0):

When you on click events, do you simply mean that you want to make things like the email address, phone # etc to be tappable, such that tapping a phone # would open the Phone app etc?

If so, have you tried simply setting the UITextView's properties in Interface Builder > Attributes Inspector.

See my image below:

[image]

Comment: thank you, but how can i call a event in HTML(in apple words:IBAction in HTML into ios)