# iOS6 audio tags in UITextView

Tags: ios, audio, ios6, hyperlink, uitextview

Is there any way to add audio tags in UITextView in iOS6.

What are audio tags?

Audio Tags are hyperlinks that point to an audio file. When the Audio Tag is clicked the file is opened and played.

Comment: **Audio Tags** hyperlinks(string format) right?

Comment: @KumarKl Yes Audio Tags are hyperlinks but in textview it is not necessary that there is a complete path mentioned. Forexample a string "a" can be linked to an audio tag.

Answer (score 1):

I hope there is a way to get using `UITextView delegate` Method:

```
 - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange{
    // Now deal with the url to play audio file

    self.theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:(__bridge NSURL *)(URL) error:NULL];
     self.theAudio.volume = 1.0;
    self.theAudio.delegate = self;
    [self.theAudio prepareToPlay];

    [self.theAudio play]; 
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Check this link, You will get for both **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543967/how-to-intercept-click-on-link-in-uitextview**